# Parse error: parse error in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code that accesses the tables users and portfolio

However I keep running into Parse error: parse error in /Users/...../Sites/..../sell.php on line 28

If someone could help me out, it'd be of great help.

```html
<?
    // require common code
    require_once("includes/common.php");
    //check for errors
    $error = false;
    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        if(empty($_POST["symbol"]))
        {
            $error = true;
            $message = "Enter a name";
        }
        else if(empty($_POST["shares"]))
        {
            $error = true;
            $message = "Enter the shares";
        }
        // check if user has the stocks and the shares
        $id = $_SESSION["id"];
        $symbol = $_POST["symbol"];
        $sharesQuery = "SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol' ";
        else if(($shares = mysql_query($sharesQuery)) == false)
        {
            $error = true;
            $message = "Don't have the stock";
        }
        // else, if everything checks out, delete it and increment the cash
        else 
        {
            $deleteQuery = "DELETE from portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol'";
            mysql_query($deleteQuery);
            $incrementQuery = "UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ($shares * lookup($symbol)->price) WHERE id = $id ";
            mysql_query($incrementQuery);

            //set the variables into session  and then redicrect to sell2
            $_SESSION["symbol"] = $_POST["symbol"];
            $_SESSION["shares"] = $_POST["shares"];
            redirect("sell2.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use code snippets only for HTML / CSS / JavaScript.

Comment: Highlight the line in which you are getting errors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where is this `else` coming in? Add a `}`:

```
} else if(($shares = mysql_query($sharesQuery)) == false)
```

Your final code will be:

```
<?

    // require common code
    require_once("includes/common.php");

    //check for errors
    $error = false;
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        if (empty($_POST["symbol"])) {
            $error   = true;
            $message = "Enter a name";
        }

        else if (empty($_POST["shares"])) {
            $error   = true;
            $message = "Enter the shares";
        }

        // check if user has the stocks and the shares
        $id     = $_SESSION["id"];
        $symbol = $_POST["symbol"];

        $sharesQuery = "SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol' ";
    } else if (($shares = mysql_query($sharesQuery)) == false) {
        $error   = true;
        $message = "Don't have the stock";
    }

    // else, if everything checks out, delete it and increment the cash

    else {
        $deleteQuery = "DELETE from portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol'";
        mysql_query($deleteQuery);

        $incrementQuery = "UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ($shares * lookup($symbol)->price) WHERE id = $id ";
        mysql_query($incrementQuery);

        //set the variables into session  and then redicrect to sell2
        $_SESSION["symbol"] = $_POST["symbol"];
        $_SESSION["shares"] = $_POST["shares"];
        redirect("sell2.php");

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

On line 28:

```
else if(($shares = mysql_query($sharesQuery)) == false)
```

You need a bracket to close the current if statement before doing an else if:

```
<?

// require common code
require_once("includes/common.php");

//check for errors
$error = false;
// check if user has the stocks and the shares
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$symbol = $_POST["symbol"];
$sharesQuery = "SELECT shares FROM portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol' ";

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    if(empty($_POST["symbol"])){
        $error = true;
        $message = "Enter a name";
    }else if(empty($_POST["shares"])){
        $error = true;
        $message = "Enter the shares";
    }else if(($shares = mysql_query($sharesQuery)) == false){
        $error = true;
        $message = "Don't have the stock";
    }else{
        $deleteQuery = "DELETE from portfolio WHERE id = $id AND symbol = '$symbol'";
        mysql_query($deleteQuery);

        $incrementQuery = "UPDATE users SET cash = cash + ($shares * lookup($symbol)->price) WHERE id = $id ";
        mysql_query($incrementQuery);

        //set the variables into session  and then redicrect to sell2
        $_SESSION["symbol"] = $_POST["symbol"];
        $_SESSION["shares"] = $_POST["shares"];
        redirect("sell2.php");

    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was silly mistake on my part, the declarations for id and symbol should have been at the top of the condition, right after isset,
Thanks for the speedy answers