# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp64\www\11\cn.php on line 9 in wamp/www

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<body>
<?php
$thongbao = " Bạn Đã Gửi Bài Viết Thành Công ! Chân Thành Cám Ơn Sự Đóng Góp Của Bạn :)";
$hoanthanh = "";
if(isset($_post[send]))
    (
include('mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php') //tham chiếu vào thư viện 
$mail = new PHPMailer; // khởi tạo đối tượng  **line 9**
$mail-> isSMTP();
$mail-> SMTPAuth = true;
$mail-> Host="tls://smtp.gmail.com:587";
$mail->Username = 'diemtran191@gmail.com';                 
$mail->Password = '.......';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';// giao thức mã hóa khi gửi mail.
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail-> CharSet = "utf-8*";// trình duyệt hiển thị nội dung kỹ tự có dấu                     

$mail->setFrom($_post["email"]);
$mail->subject= $_post["tiêu đề"];
$mail->body= "<strong>nội dung</strong>";
$mail->addAddress('diemtran191@gmail', 'Diễm Trần');
if(!$mail->send())
{
    echo "<p>Gửi Bài Không Thành Công !! </p>";
    echo"mailer error: ".$mail->ErrorInFo;
else
{
    $hoanthanh =$thongbao;
}
```

I just used phpmailer libraby in [github.com](https://github.com/) then connect it with my web. Please help me.

Comment: Can I see your full code? Its incomplete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse error: parse error in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678032/parse-error-parse-error-in-php)

Comment: your error is on line 9. And you can see that you're missing a semi-colon there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon after your include which makes PHP not expect to find the $mail variable on the next line. Simply add a semicolon to the following line:

```
include('mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

Comment: yes i fixed it and t got another error . Undefined property: PHPMailer::$ErrorInFo. can you help me with it ??